# the h2 database driver giving out driver not found message

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, h2

I have been learning JDBC connectivity for a few days and tried this code recently using h2 relational database. I am getting a message as driver not available, I have checked and the driver is there where it should be in the lib
folder of eclipse package. What should I probably do?

```
package jdbcwork;

//importing java commands
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Manager1 
{
//main method with exception throw
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException    
    {
    //try block
    try
        {

    //calling the h2 database driver org.h2.Driver
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");

    //declaring host ,username and password 
    String host="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test/INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS";
    String uName="sa";
    String uPass="sa";

    //giving a connection to the h2 database driver driver 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("h2","sa","sa");

        }
    //catch block
    catch(SQLException err)
        {
        //printing an error message
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());       
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the H2 driver jar to the class path of your application? Also please post the **exact** exception stacktrace, don't just describe the error message inexactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//declaring host ,username and password 
    String host="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test/INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS";
    String uName="sa";
    String uPass="sa";

    //giving a connection to the h2 database driver driver 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("h2","sa","sa");
```

Change like:

```
//declaring host ,username and password 
    String host="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test/INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS";
    String uName="sa";
    String uPass="sa";

    //giving a connection to the h2 database driver driver 
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);
```

**and make sure** `h2.jar` **must have into your classpath**

if want to donwload check this :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadh2jar.htm

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

Use your database name and all

```
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class OracleJDBC {

        public static void main(String[] argv) {

            System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

            try {

                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;

            }

            System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

            Connection connection = null;

            try {

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","murali123");

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;

            }

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }
        }

    }
```

Here you will know that where is the problem occuring .Try this tell me the output you are getting.

Comment: op is just need to add h2 driver jar in classpath. your answer oracle db connection make no sense. @Jay answer is correct and just check it.

Comment: @KetanG am in chennai!!

Comment: just for remark, the database username could be also `username="sa"` and `password=""` (empty  string)